# Why for...of stops?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a piece of HTML:

```
<a name="list">the list</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
  <li><a href="ftp://ftp.com/my.zip">ftp://ftp.com/my.zip</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://nodejs.org">http://nodejs.org</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://internal.com/test">http://internal.com/test</a></li>
</ul>
```

and a piece of JS:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let link of links) {
  let href = link.getAttribute('href');
  alert(href.includes("://"))
```

The question is why the JS above doesn't work (it should display true/false), but works if I add an if-condition:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (let link of links) {
  let href = link.getAttribute('href');
  if (!href) continue;
  alert(href.includes("://"))
```

Comment: are you closing your for loops with `}` ?

Comment: You are iterating over all `<a>`'s and the first match (`<a name="list"></a>`) does not have an href attribute but in the first snippet you are trying to access href which returns `undefined` resulting in an `cannot read property includes of undefined`. Therefore breaking the program.

Comment: This question is self-contained enough to be answered; I don't understand the reason for the close-vote.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work when you didn't add `if` statement because there is a case `href` returns `null` for the link list you are trying.
For your information, I share the `console.log` message when it doesn't work.

```
VM260:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')
at <anonymous>:4:14
```

If you add `if` statement, then the `includes` is not executed in the code snippet. Hope that's clear to you.

Comment: I thought a for...of loop works even if one of iterations causes an error... Ok, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad you got me.